# flexbox container does not stretch 100% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I have the following html and css:
HTML:

```
<body style="height:100%;">
  <div class="fb-container">
    <div class"somedatadiv">
      Some data
    </div>
    <div class="anotherdiv">
      data
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.fb-container { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  // min-height: 100%;
}
.somedatadiv {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 345px;
  backround: grey;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

for some reason the flex container div is not stretching 100% of the body height.

(the browser I am using is chrome for this "demo/application/site")

Comment: From OP's answer below: *"There was some code missplaced in the MCV template. that was messing up the style/layout. this post is not relevant for other users so it will be removed/deleted. Update: Can not delete this post:*".

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `display:flex` to the parent tag for and then `flex:1` to the child to enable the child to expand to 100% of parent.

```css
.fb-container { 
  background-color:green;
  flex: 1;
  
}
.somedatadiv {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 345px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body style="height:100vh;display:flex;">
  <div class="fb-container">
    <div class="somedatadiv">
      Some data
    </div>
    <div class="anotherdiv">
      data
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: same here, thank you but the data div is no longer 345 px width anymore. it is less than the value I have declared in my css

Comment: You have declared the max width. If you want the div to be minimum 345px you would need to declare it like wise.

Comment: 75% width with a max of 345px; on a full hd screen this is no issue. it worked before the change. why should it not work anymore. there is something wrong going on it i place the flex property on the body

Comment: thank you for the update. there was something wrom in the mvc tempate. I thought it was my update but it was already wrong in the template. I will remove this post. because its not relevant for other users

Answer (score 4):

add this and it should work. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/svtewj9j/

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}
```

---

**update**: if you want the fb-container to stay full width

add `flex: 1 1 100%;` to it

```
.fb-container {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

---

**update**: complete solution https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/svtewj9j/2/

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

.fb-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.somedatadiv {
  flex: 1 1 75%;
  max-width: 345px;
  backround: grey;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works for the height but my width will be chopped of. the data div is no longer 345px.

Comment: JSfiddle not working. There is no HTML in the answer. So the answer is not possible to test. JSFiddle is **not** replacement for code inside answer

Answer (score -2):

There was some code missplaced in the MCV template.
that was messing up the style/layout.
this post is not relevant for other users so it will be removed/deleted

update: Can not delete this post: